# Amarok and Dragon Player Won't Play CD's or DVD's

Tags: dvd, cd

In my Dell Latitude D620 with Ubuntu 15.04 will not play CD's or DVD's with Amarok and Dragon Player, respectively.
I am a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Did U already install the package *kubuntu-restricted-extras* ?

If yes, proceed further:
Open a terminal window and execute (just use copy+paste for the line):

`sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

The command invokes a download and installation of libdvdcss. Check with the laws if this is legal in your region.

This information is derived from
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs#Ubuntu_12.04_up_to_15.04_.28i386.2C_amd64.29

Tested & works

Comment: @ellisisfroh I'm not sure. When I installed the distro, I checked "Install 3rd Party Programs." Or something to that effect.
 Sorry about taking so long to reply. I don't have internet at home.

Comment: Without  internet-connection you can only check if the package which can invoke the script is installed: `dpkg-query -l libdvdread4` It's anyway a good idea to run updates on a machine/Laptop in order to receive bugfixes. Some family-visit could help? Other options are Ubuntu-meetings in your area (they offer PC-Doctor sometimes) Or a Linux-User-Group (LUG) - not knowing if they are fond on the idea of helping on this, depends on the people (nerds?) involved - and the way they get approached.